# poner falsa localización para obtener idioma

Tags: java, idioma, android-spinner, traducción, localización

Estoy trabajando en  una app de android studio  y de lenguaje java.
En el fragmento de actividad principal,tengo un Spinner de idiomas.
el Spinner tiene su archivo xml asociado.
quiero traducir la app directamente con la position selecctionada por el usuario sin pasar por el (SettingLanguage de Android).

Tengo esta la configuración siguiente que me funciona de momento:

```
 btnLangue = vista.findViewById(R.id.btnLangue);

        /*intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");*/


        btnLangue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿cómo puedo traducir la app directamente con la posición de los elementos del Spinner cuando es seleccionada por el usuario?
osea,cuando el usuario elije un idoma.

Quiero una traducción directa

tengo los archivos xml de traducciones listos en cincos idiomas: español, francés,inglés,alemán,árabe.

lo dejo el código :

Aquí mi xml del Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="spinner_langue">
        <item>Langue</item>
        <item>Français</item>
        <item>Anglais</item>
        <item>Allemand</item>
        <item>Espagnol</item>
        <item>Arabe</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Aquí mi Spinner ArrayAdapter:

```
 spinnerLangue = vista.findViewById(id.spinnerFragmentGallery);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                array.spinner_langue, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerLangue.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinnerLangue.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            


            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
                if (position == 1) {
                    
                }
                if (position == 2) {

                }
                if (position == 3) {

                }
                if (position == 4) {

                }
                   
            }
            


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

aquí por ejemplo mi xml Español:

```
<string name="Langue">Idioma</string>
    <string name="Français">Frances</string>
    <string name="Anglais">Ingles</string>
    <string name="Allemand">Aleman</string>
    <string name="Espagnol">Español</string>
    <string name="Arabe">Árabe</string>
```

Aquí por ejemplo mi xml en ingles:

```
<string name="Langue">Language</string>
    <string name="Français">French</string>
    <string name="Anglais">English</string>
    <string name="Allemand">German</string>
    <string name="Espagnol">Spanish</string>
    <string name="Arabe">Arabic</string>
```

y mas..........

Comment: Tu pregunta me resulta un poco confusa. ¿Podrías editarla?

Comment: @Mateo ya esta modificada y con  código nuevo para aclarar un poco más.

Answer (score 0):

aquí esta la solución,por si alguien lo necesita.
Gracias @Mateo por contestarme.
el siguiente código es  para francés de Francia

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Resources res = getResources();

                if (position == 1) {
                    Locale locale = new Locale("fr", "FR");
                    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
                    Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();
                    configuration.locale = locale;
                    res.updateConfiguration(configuration, displayMetrics);
```